# Let moderators edit /help/dont-ask

Tags: support, feature-request, moderator-tools

The [help center page “What types of questions should I avoid asking?”](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) is linked from a few places where people occasionally find it, including:

- [the help center page “What topics can I ask about here?”](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- [the help center entry point](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help) where it's the second item in the first section
- comments about why a question is being closed
- some moderator message templates

Unfortunately, this page focuses on things that are mostly irrelevant to this site: a fairly verbose explanation of “bad subjective”. This doesn't correspond to the kind of undesirable questions that we do get on this site, so the content on this page is unhelpful and distracting. The kind of bad questions we do get are primarily computer-not-science question (programming assignments, my-computer-won't-boot, etc.) and homework dumps; this is what the help center page should mention.

Moderators can edit (a large part of) the `/help/on-topic` page. Please allow us to edit `/help/dont-ask` as well.

There are a few other help center page that could use work, like [the formatting help](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) which doesn't even mention MathJax. [Most if not all help center page should be editable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279879/improved-help-center-site-specific-pages-and-site-specific-edits-to-all-pages). I think `/help/dont-ask` is the most important one here.